# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal

Tags: php, laravel, forms, bootstrap-modal, laravel-5.7

> why can't view modal ?
>   **and error like this**

[image]

> it should be like this

[image]

Comment: show your code also

Comment: The line above: "_bootstrap.js 404 (Not found)._" Load bootstrap.js and all should be fine

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- BS JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- Have fun using Bootstrap JS -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#prizePopup').modal('show');
});
</script>`

Comment: its the problem with your bootstrap file that was not attached to you dom

Comment: so what should be repaired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// jQuery
   $('.edit_real').on('click', function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $('#edit_real').modal();
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this way:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- BS JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- Have fun using Bootstrap JS -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#prizePopup').modal('show');
});
</script>
```